# How to give collateral loan for car in India?

Tags: india, loans, collateral

My neighbour wants a loan on his car.  What are the legal procedure to give such a loan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create loan agreement and register it. Plus sign up papers for hypothecation with RTO.

You would need to pay taxes on interest. Please consult a lawyer and CA.

Given the costs involved it doesn't make sense.